# Alamofire request with SwiftyJSON parameters

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

I would like to know how I can put a SwiftyJSON array into my parameters for the Alamofire request.

Actually I use this code (Swift 3) to setup the parameters for the request:

```
let params = ["customObjects": customObjects.map({$0.toJSON()})]
```

...but this fires an exception if I try to start the request:

```
uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (_SwiftValue)'
```

The "customObjects" are an array of my custom model class.

If you need any more information let me know.

Comment: "..but this fires an exception" What exception?

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: What does `toJSON()` do exactly? Does it returns only Dictionary, Array, String and Int?

Comment: It returns a JSON (from SwiftyJSON) like: let json: JSON = ["key": "value"]. All values inside are String or Int

Comment: Could you check that `let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options: [])` works? If not, `let jsonData2 = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: customObjects.map({$0.toJSON(), options: [])`

Comment: Dinner time now. Will check this in about an hour, but thanks so far!

Comment: The most likely reason of this type of errors is that some of the properties of your objects are either `nil` or optionals. They are **not** automatically unwrapped/converted to JSON `null`s - you need to unwrap them/map them to `NSNull` yourself.

Comment: I tried your code @Larme but it didn't work. I tried to convert my model to NSDictionary and this worked great. If I try to convert that NSDictionary to json with JSONSerialization... it crashs too. To crizzis : All my properties are initialized and not null.

Comment: "My code" was to check if your data is really JSON. If `jsonData` is nil in my case, then it's not valid. You need to show `customObjects`, and what does really `toJSON()`. Also, as I said, JSON can have only String, Int, Dictionaries or Array (and null too), on each levels and sublevels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by myself:

```
let params = ["customObjects": customObjects.map({$0.toDictionary()})]
```

And here the toDictionary() func inside my CustomObject:

```
func toDictionary() -> [String: Any] {
    let dict: [String: Any] = [
        "exampleKey": "exampleValue",
        "exampleKey2": "exampleValue2"
    ]

    return dict
}
```

I guess this is because you can setup Alamofire with `encoding: JSONEncoding.default`.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert a SwiftyJSON object (called `yourJSON` here) to parameters like so:

```
let parameters : Parameters = yourJSON.dictionaryObject ?? [:]
```

Then you can use it in an Alamofire request like so:

```
Alamofire.request("https://yourURL.com/somePath", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding:  JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { response in
   // ... do whatever you would like with the response 
}
```